# How to improve this class in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I wrote this class (below) but my compiler shows errors.Someone knows what is wrong here ? Thank you for your help and sorry for my english, I have just start learning.

I wrote this class to convert grade: with letters on percent and vice versa. But something is wrong, could you gelp me solve this issue?

ABOUT ERRORS:

```
10:89: error: 'constexpr' needed for in-class initialization of static data member 'char Grade::grade_map [15]' of non-integral type [-fpermissive] 
11:55: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'Grade::letter' 
11:55: error: scalar object 'Grade::letter' requires one element in initializer 
14:12: error: expected ':' before 'Grade' In constructor 'Grade::Grade()': 
17:30: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer 
16:19: warning: unused variable 'grade_map' [-Wunused-variable] 
17:19: warning: unused variable 'letter' [-Wunused-variable] 
18:11: warning: unused variable 'percent' [-Wunused-variable] In function 'int main()': 
48:125: error: no matching function for call to 'Grade::printGrade(Grade&)' 
48:125: note: candidate is: 
33:6: note: void Grade::printGrade(Grade*) 
33:6: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Grade' to 'Grade*' 
45:8: warning: unused variable 'geade_map' [-Wunused-variable] 
46:8: warning: unused variable 'letter' [-Wunused-variable]
```

This is my class in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

    class Grade // my class

    {
      public:

    static char grade_map [15]; 
    static char letter;
    int  percent;

     public Grade ()
          {                         
     static char grade_map [15];
      static char letter[20]='A';
      int percent = 1;
        }

        void setGradeByPercent(Grade * grade, int percent) 
         {
           grade->percent = percent;
          grade->letter = grade_map [percent / 10];
         }

        void setGradeByLetter(Grade * grade, char letter)
       {
         grade->letter = letter;
         grade->percent = 100 - (letter - 'A') * 10 - 5;
         }

        void printGrade(Grade * grade)
        {
           printf("Grade: %d: %c\n", grade->percent, grade->letter);
        }  

         };

           **int main ()**

           {
              Grade g;
              int percent;
             char grade_map[15];
              char letter[20];

          cout << "Enter two grades separated by a space. Use                            percentage       for         first and       letter   for the second: " << g.printGrade (g) << endl;

       scanf("%d", &percent);
       scanf("\n");    

         g.setGradeByPercent(&g, percent);
         g.printGrade(&g);
           g.setGradeByLetter(&g, getchar());
          g.printGrade(&g);

                     return 0;
              }
```

Comment: If you could write a little more descriptive title, that would be awesome.

Also, **obviously, the exact compiler errors are important**. Please copy&paste them into your question. You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" button below it.

Comment: What error(s)? Please post a [mcve] and format it properly.

Comment: Hm, @BaummitAugen, I can't trust your nickname: From your existence follows that eyes can't be circular.

Comment: Besides, text formatting is disabled inside code blocks, therefore please don't try to write `int main()` in bold, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do not write this much code all at once. Start with something small and simple, get it to work perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, test at every step and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: The code formatting is horrible, the errors aren't readable. Please put some efforts beyond copy & paste, when writing questions or answers!

Comment: It looks like the errors don't match the code you posted

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nice, good one! I literally laughed out loud. =D

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is with the constructor, where you first need a colon after `public` and then use a totally wrong way of initializing the class members.

If you simplify to this, at least it will compile:

```
public:
   Grade()
   {                         
       letter='A';
       percent = 1;
   }
```

A second problem is that you have `g.printGrade (g)` as an argument to `cout`. However, the function returns `void` so can't be printed.